# First step in pulsing a pulsed laser diode

Tags: pulse, laser

here is the datasheet for the laser im looking at https://dammedia.osram.info/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-2496525/SPL%20LL90_3.pdf
All i want to know is where i even start, i see the input voltage is only 20v and it can pulse at < 30ns so with this information where do i start? I learned how a to make a CW laser driver circuit for any laser and i know this is a lot more difficult, but any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You are best to search and read all the App notes for product handling , safety and design.  Elantec EL7104C
- Micrel MIC4452 were suggested with 15V for Vgs max and 18.5V for supply voltage which controls the peak power.

Comment: To ensure proper operation of the MOSFET
driver several guidelines have to be
observed. Problems that can occur are
CMOS latch-up, over-voltage spikes,
insufficient overdrive and thermal overload.
These phenomena and their prevention are
described in the Elantec application note
#25 ‘Applying Power MOSFET Drivers’ [4]
by using bypassing capacitors, clamping
Schottky diodes and external resistors.
Useful application information are also given
in data sheet of the Micrel MIC4452 [2].

Comment: so EL7104C - Micrel MIC4452 are the same thing but the MIC4452 is more efficent in increasing the amps without other components??

Comment: When you learn to locate the App Note to get started you will have learned to find all your own answers and more that you must know to be successful.  Then come back with a better question.  Other parts are needed.

Comment: heres what i learned. the purpose of the MOSFET is once the gate is triggered it discharges the capacitors releasing its pulse. the length of the laser pulse is determined by the capacitors. and the only way the diode can pulse so fast with great power is because the MOSFET is able to quickly obtain high energy levels. I also learned that you need 2 power supplies for capcitors and MOSFET.

Comment: Yes 20V is ABS MAX and 18.5V is rated for Laser diode with 15V for Gate.  ( using some method limiter )  Did you find the App note yet with the schematic?  yes it is a combination of Q=CV Cap discharge method pulse width regulated peak power and rep rate..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain the short optical pulses, the
MOSFET gate has to be charged very fast.
The MOSFET has a gate capacitance of 300
pF. To obtain the required gate-source
threshold voltage of 5 V the gate must be
charged with about 7 nAs within several
nanoseconds. Therefore a pulsed trigger
current of about 1 A is required. Such a
signal can be generated by a high speed
power MOSFET driver IC which itself is
triggered by a TTL-level voltage signal.
As MOSFET driver we can suggest the
following types

- Elantec EL7104C
- Micrel MIC4452

The MOSFET inside the hybrid package is
the Infineon BSP318S .
[image]

It is rated for 18.5V on pin 2 and 15V on trigger pin 1.